# Creating Photo Gallery with Silverlight in Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm looking to create an app that features a photo gallery, one that is almost exactly the same as the built in photo gallery/photos hub.

I've looked at using a Grid, but I can't bind data to it. I also looked at using a DataGrid, but that is not included in the Windows Phone SDK. The grid I need will have a set number of columns but a variable number of rows (like I said, just like the current built in photo gallery)

Does anyone have any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Exact duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474353/image-photo-gallery-like-built-in-wp7

Comment: No - he is building a photo viewer. I need to build the photo gallery/grid.

Comment: I have looked for several days for the answer to this question, and I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Photo gallery is simply a listbox where every row is an horizontal stackpanel with images, add a little binding and you are ok ;)

Answer (score 2):

It will work with a listbox, but you have to edit its ItemsPanelTemplate and use something like the WrapPanel control (horizontal orientation) from the toolkit. Then, you can define the ItemTemplate as a square image. That way every new item will stack at the right from the other until there's no more room and it will continue on the next row. So for a set number of columns, you have to specify the width in the item template (173 in my example so in the portrait mode,  i end with 2 columns).

Here's a example from one of my projects (you should adjust bindings and names to your scenario):

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxCategorias" ItemsSource="{Binding ChannelButtons}"  
                         SelectionChanged="lbxCategorias_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding BigButtonIconPath}" Width="173" Height="173" Margin="0 0 12 10" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: I was going to post this answer if it wasn't already here. FWIW, images in the pictures hub are 96x96 for four columns.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone SDK contains a Panorama/Pivot Control that mimics the functionality you see in the people or photos hub.

Here's a link to a code sample using this control:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

Scroll down to the Controls section of the samples page and the first item there is the Panorama Sample.

I'd also recommend taking a look at the section titled Cameras and Photos.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I'm looking to create the grid that displays when you choose an album from within the photos hub. For example, when you click on "Camera Roll" you get a grid of photos/videos that you can choose from. How would I create something like that?

Comment: Set up a grid, load the images in it and then encase the control in a scrollviewer

Comment: So do I need to do that in my code-behind? I was hoping I could do this with data binding, but are you saying that I need to manually add rows to the grid from my code-behind?

Comment: @bfink You could create a ListBox, and have it's ItemTemplate be a HorizontalOrientated Grid with 3 Images, which you could bind to / hide if nothing exists. What you're describing isn't too difficult, you might want to look into a tutorial if you're unsure.

Comment: Thanks willmel, I will look into using a ListBox/Horizontal Grid. Any other suggestions are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a exact photo viewer like in wp7 using the horizontal looping selector with some modifications. Try to add the images in the item i think it helps you

http://blog.supaywasi.com/2011/06/horizontal-looping-selector/