# Photo Gallery in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, photo-gallery, pinchzoom

do you know how I can make a photo gallery like that default used by smartphone? For example in my project I add 10 images. I want to make 2 photo gallery, one by a topic, so for example I must put 5 photos in a photo gallery and other 5 photos in the second photo gallery (in several pages of project). I would like in these photo gallery,  zoomable and scrollable images with touch. Can you write me a code example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Silverlight Control Toolkit's gesture listener to capture Drag and Pinch from touch.

Define a CompositeTransformation for your image and set it's scale (on pinch) and Offset (in drag). When the image is not zoom, drag can trigger going to next image.

For further details see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6474498/1150183.
- [Creating Photo Gallery with Silverlight in Windows Phone 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299137/creating-photo-gallery-with-silverlight-in-windows-phone-7-5)

You can also try http://multitouch.codeplex.com/, if you want pinch zoom functionality.

Comment: Following first link, in the C# code, I have an error on OffsetX: "System.Media.CompositeTransform doesn't contain a definition of OffsetX".